# Where do you set the a UITableView's height or frame? AwakeFromNib?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview in my app that I built in a NIB where I set the height via the Size Inspector to 68.

I also do the following in my code.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,68);
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 68;
}
```

When I run the app in the simulator or iPhone it looks fine, as the table is only 68px tall. If I close the app (go to the home screen) and reopen it the table is no longer only 68px tall, but it takes up the entire screen.

I can't seem to make it stay 68px all the time?

Besides my question above is there a method (awakeFromNib, ViewDidAppear, etc...) where you should always and only set the size or position of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own solution.  The solution per Apple is that if you are using a UITableView and other subviews then don't use a uitbalviewcontroller, as the tableview will always try to use the entire screen.  The solution is to use a uiview as the base with a uiviewcontroller then put a uitableview in the uiview and give the uiviewcontroller the delegate methods it needs to manage the tableview.

So just remember, if you don't want a full height uitableview then don't use a uitableviewcontroller with menubar.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to set the height,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return 68;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code into viewWillApper, that may work!

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,68);
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
self.tableView.rowHeight = 68;
```

}